# how to inherit a #include class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have 4 files,

```
HomeScene.h
HomeScene.cpp
Options.h
Options.cpp
```

both the `*.h` files have the other `*.h` included.
Now I am trying to inherit HomeScene.h in Options.h

```
class OptionScene : public cocos2d::CCLayerColor,HomeScene
```

the above line gives so many errors.

```
class OptionScene : public cocos2d::CCLayerColor
```

the above line has no errors

I have a `static bool var;` in my `HomeScene.h`
which I am trying to use directly in my options scene.

Comment: What errors do you get?  It would help to know ...

Comment: Please post the errors. And try to get rid of the circular dependency.

Comment: error C2039: 'HomeScene' : is not a member of '_STL'

Comment: error C2385: ambiguous access of 'autorelease'

Comment: error C2594: 'argument' : ambiguous conversions from 'OptionScene *' to 'cocos2d::CCNode *'

Comment: error C2594: 'type cast' : ambiguous conversions from 'void (__thiscall OptionScene::* )(cocos2d::CCObject *)' to 'cocos2d::SEL_MenuHandler'

Comment: ok , 4get it. i am using members functions to get and set those values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to include `Options.h` in `HomeScene.h` ? If `OptionScene` is the type derived from `HomeScene`, then I don't know why would you need to do that.

In case you just need to declare pointer / reference to the type declared in `Options.h`, you could use forward declaration.

Options.h

```
#include "HomeScene.h"
class OptionScene
{
    // ...
};
```

HomeScene.h

```
class OptionScene; // forward declaration

class HomeScene
{
    OptionScene* o;
};
```

If this is your problem, then this question will help you: [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)